# In Android AsyncTasks run before splash screen displays?

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a splash screen that I'm trying to run some AsyncTasks on. It appears the AsyncTasks are running before it shows the splash screen. I need the splash screen to show (logo and each process shows a different message) and the start running the asynctasks. I'm using books in the blow code only as an example of what I have:

SplashScreen.java:

```
// Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;
    TextView statusMessage;

    BookClubDB bookClubDB = new BookClubDB(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        statusMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.statusMessage);

        statusMessage.setText("Checking For Connection");
        if(isNetworkAvailable()){
            statusMessage.setText("Connection Found");

            String appUpdateDate = null;
            appUpdateDate = lastUpdate();

            update1(appUpdateDate);
            update2(appUpdateDate);
            update3(appUpdateDate);
            update4(appUpdateDate);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    endSplash();
                }

            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
        else {
            statusMessage.setText("No Connection Found");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    endSplash();
                }

            }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
        }
    }

    public void endSplash(){

        Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        // close this activity
        finish();

    }

    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    private String lastUpdate(){
        String updateDate = null;

        updateDate = bookClubDB.getUpdateDate();

        return updateDate;

    }

    private void update1(String appUpdateDate){

        statusMessage.setText("Updating Regions");
        bookClubDB.getAPI1(appUpdateDate);

    }

    private void update2(String appUpdateDate){

        statusMessage.setText("Updating Vehicles");
        bookClubDB.getAPI2(appUpdateDate);

    }

    private void update3(String appUpdateDate){

        statusMessage.setText("Updating Products");
        bookClubDB.getAPI3(appUpdateDate);

    }

    private void update4(String appUpdateDate){

        statusMessage.setText("Updating Documents, Images, and Video");
        bookClubDB.getAPI4(appUpdateDate);

    }
```

The functions being called (updated1...4) call another function (getAPI1...4) in a file called BookClubDB.java. The second set is what runs the asynctasts in a file named JASONParser.java. The functions and parser work. Only the asynctasks run before the splash screen shows.

I want the splash screen to pop up with "checking for connection" -> "connection found" -> each updated from the functions as they are ran.

The JSONParser.java is a simple json parser that returns the json results back to the BookClubDB.java:

```
JSONObject output = new JSONParser().execute(new String[] {bookClubURL,consumerKey,sharedSecret}).get();
```

The function takes the json, converts it into a jsonArray and I populate a database with it. Again everything is working as needed, only the asynctasks are running too soon.

How can I start the thread for the splash screen before the asynctask thread? I've looked at other SO answers but they never really answered it for me.

Comment: I don't see you using AsyncTask anywhere in your code? And further you are calling `update1(appUpdateDate);
            update2(appUpdateDate);
            update3(appUpdateDate);
            update4(appUpdateDate);` consecutively within `onCreate()`, which would then only apply the last change made in `update4(appUpdateDate);`

Answer (score 0):

You are running all of your code in the OnCreate method of your activity. The UI is not yet visible at this point.

Check out the activity lifecycle in the Android docs and rewrite according to that.

Comment: I'm now attempting to use the onStart meathod but it crashes when I attempt to run any of the functions such as 'update1(appUpdateDate);' Without the functions in the onStart it runs fine (aside from not populating the database)

Comment: Check the reason for the exception by looking at your logcat and resolve the cause. Also, OnResume is  better than OnStart as it is the callback called before your UI is available.

Comment: I had to restart Eclipse to get my LogCat to display. I placed my "statusMessage.setText("Updating Regions");" in my bookClubDB.java but it's complaining because I'm referencing a TextView that is not in that activity. It's in SplashScreen.java

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is happening because you are firing asynctasks in activity's onCreate, when the activity is still being created.
If I understood correctly, you want them to be triggered only after the splash screen was displayed.

`onResume`  is a good callback for that.

Moreover, notice that you are firing all the updatexx methods at the same time, and the status message will be overridden every time.

Comment: I'm now attempting to use the onStart method based on the lifecylce but it crashes when I attempt to run any of the functions such as 'update1(appUpdateDate);' Without the functions in the onStart it runs fine (aside from not populating the database)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because you are setting the message text on main thread.

If you run some changes on main thread too quickly, they don't have to be performed or may result in lags in the UI.

Basically your app is doing something like this:

-> OnCreate

-> setText("Checking For Connection")

-> setText("OnConnectionFound")

-> setText("Updating Regions")

-> schedule new AsyncTask to update regions

-> setText("Updating Vehicles")

-> schedule new AsyncTask to update vehicles

..... update3,4......

and only now the system starts to execute the async tasks. 
(It does not have to be this strict, especially on multicore processors. It is possible that f.e. the regions asyncTask starts before the update3 setText, but it certainly does not finish before that)
But there is one thing you need to realize: all these calls are quite fast, probably no more then few miliseconds. And the UI is not updated that often (nor would you notice it).

Therefore the text updates too quickly/does not update at all.

You mentioned you are using AsyncTask, that's good. You will probably just have to place your setText calls into onPreExecute/onPostExecute/onProgressChanged methods (based on when you want the text to be changed) and it will work fine. These methods are designed to be called on UI thread in the right time, therefore ensure all your UI actions will be rendered :)

Comment: thanks for insight on the text. Actually address a concern I had but haven't had time to test yet.

Comment: I need to target the textview (statusMessage) but statusMessage is part of the SplashScreen.java activity not the JSONParser.java and will/does cause an error.

Comment: I can think of those options here: 
A) Define some "callback" interface, something like onTextUpdate(String message). Implement it in your Activity, so that every time someone calls it, you set the message in your textView. Pass this interface to your bookClubDB, then call onTextUpdate from your asyncTasks.
B) Pass reference to your textView to the bookClubDB constructor. Then work with view directly. Dirty, but will do the work
C) Don't do update 1-4 in separate asyncTasks. Define them as simple methods and call them from one "big" asyncTask managed directly from your Activity.